# Prevent Specific User from Deleting Comments

Tags: discussion, comments

I recently asked a question on Stack Overflow, where a commenter with high reputation (180k) commented "This kind of code works for everybody else."  I responded with a comment questioning whether he even tried to run the code before claiming it works.  The other user deleted my comment since he has a high enough reputation to do so.

Is there a way to restore my comment?  It seems really inappropriate that someone is able (and does) remove responses to his own comments, when all I was asking for were specifics on how he was able to get it to work.  Is there some way to prevent deletion by that user so I can publicly question whether his statement has any evidence to support it?

Comment: *"The other user deleted my comment since he has a high enough reputation to do so."* No such privileged exists. Only moderators can do this. The only thing they could do themselves would be delete their post which has the comment.

Comment: Nope. High reputation doesn't allow someone to delete a comment. Likely it was flagged and removed by a moderator.

Comment: Looking into it - the comment was rude, therefore flagged and deleted. Rightly so.

Comment: @Oded Can you please explain how the comment was rude?  I don't understand.  Are you able to somehow view deleted comments?

Comment: @JeffG Yes. Moderators can view deleted comments.

Comment: It accuses the user of arrogance, in a most arrogant manner. Kinda funny really.

Comment: That is why I wanted to see the comment.  From memory, I wrote: "*I would avoid statements like "This kind of code works for everybody else.", because it has an arrogant tone.*"  That is NOT calling him arrogant.  Perhaps I should have used the word condescending, but either way, I don't see how that is rude.  I was trying to bring up the fact that he was [talking down to the reader](http://www.hollymessinger.com/writing/talkingdown.html).  It is frustrating that I can't see the comment, can't see why it was flagged or removed, and therefore, can never learn from my mistakes.

Comment: The exact text of your deleted comment: `I have traced the value of `port`. The value I specify is correctly being propagated all the way to the call to `bind0`, which I can't step into because it is native code. I will also advise you to avoid statements like "This kind of code works for everybody else". That statement has an arrogant tone, and is so vague that I must conclude that you didn't actually run the code before typing it. If you did run the code, then tell me the specifics of 1) what JVM you are using, 2) on what platform, and 3) the ports that succeeded.`

Comment: @BradLarson Thank you for posting.  Perhaps after the sentence ending with "native code", I should have said: *Be careful using blanket statements like "This kind of code works for everybody else".  Its tone appears to me to be condescending.  If you ran the code and it worked for you, please provide more specifics of 1) what JVM you are using, 2) on what platform, and 3) the ports that succeeded.*  Do you think that is a better wording?  Perhaps it would help if there was a wiki with concrete examples of rude things that *have* been said on SO, and how to fix them to be more constructive.

Comment: @JeffG - In general, I'd recommend against any language that makes a negative personal statement about someone. "I must conclude that you didn't actually run the code before typing it" seems to also imply something negative about the other person, and thus also comes across as rude. I would address the "This kind of code works for everybody else" statement directly with why this isn't working for you, without providing commentary on tone or intent. In my experience, as soon as you start confronting someone about the tone of their comments, the conversation tends to go in a bad direction.

Comment: @BradLarson OK.  Thank you very much for taking the time to explain my mistake.  I wish this kind of feedback was easier to get, since it will enable me to improve my SO contributions moving forward.  Perhaps an auto-generated e-mail when a comment is removed for being rude that says, "One of your comments was recently removed after being flagged as rude.  Please visit our wiki (would be a link in the e-mail) on how to write courteous, constructive comments for more information."  Of course, that assumes such a wiki exists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The other user deleted my comment since he has a high enough reputation to do so.

Unless he is a moderator that is not possible. You can't delete comments from other users no matter how high your reputation is (it can be *flagged* by another user though).

A moderator must have deleted it, possibly because it was rude or just wasn't useful enough to stay. In all this remember that comments are second-class citizens and that they can be deleted whenever a moderator thinks it is appropriate or necessary.